# Django User Model: add extra behavior when saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am using Django 1.6.11 and I want to basically add more additional behavior when a User Model is changed on Django admin site. Currently what I am doing is like this in `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAdmin, self).save_model(
            request, obj, form, change, *args, **kwargs)
        if change and obj.groups.filter(name='GTO').exists():
            user_perms = obj.user_permissions.all()
            print(user_perms)
            # and do something else

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

The only problem with this is that `obj` does not contain current change: so if obj previously does not belong to `'GTO'` group. Now someone adds the group to the user on Django admin website `obj.groups.filter(name='GTO').exists()` will still return `False`. Also `user_perms` is not correctly reflected as current change as well.

So how should I capture the "current" state of the user and do something about it?

Comment: put flag in User table like is_active or something and access based on your condition

Comment: How about saving your object with obj.save() instead of doing the super call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using is m2m_changed signals on `User.groups.through` and `User.user_permissions.through`